# How to delete a model in LoopBack?

Tags: loopbackjs

Is there a command to delete a model in LoopBack? 
The command to create a model is:

```
slc loopback
```

But I can't find how to delete a model...

Comment: There is no tool for this. Delete manually `my-model.js`, `my-model.json` and also delete the corresponding record in `model-config.json`

Answer (score 0):

Go into your loopback project folder and delete the files associated with the model from directory `/common/models/` or `/server/models/`.
Then go into `/server/` directory and delete the model's config object from the file `model-config.json`